# How to create Picturebox in VB.net web application?

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio, web-applications, picturebox

I work with vb.net web application and I want to create picture box which I can upload a picture in it. Is it possible to create it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you might be looking for the [`<asp:Image />`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image) control.